# Fastai 1.0.x use torchvision model

Tags: python, fast-ai, torchvision

Can someone show me an example of how to use a torchvision model in fastai without modification (i.e. without the network modifications made by `create_cnn`)? I've tried this, but am getting `RuntimeError: size mismatch`. I think the alexnet input size is supposed to be 224, so not sure how to debug.

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_name_re(path_img, 
                                   get_image_files(path/'images'), 
                                   r'/([^/]+)_\d+.jpg$', 
                                   ds_tfms=None, size=224, bs=16)

learn = create_cnn(data, models.alexnet, metrics=error_rate, 
                   custom_head=models.alexnet(num_classes=data.c).classifier)

print(learn.summary())
```